# Rename columns in a Pandas Dataframe dynamically and write it to S3 as CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, amazon-s3

I am new to pandas and python. I have a requirement to read a `csv` file from s3 into a `Pandas DF` and then, **dynamically** rename the columns as mentioned in a Python `list`. The new column names in the `list` will be in the same order as the columns in the csv.

Then I need to write this renamed pd dataframe as a csv file in a folder on S3 named `datetime=20230506112312`. The times-stamp part that you see in the folder-name should be the current timestamp. The csv file written should have the name as - `export_current_20230506112312.csv`

Please let me know if additional information is required.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We could do that with `boto3`, first we install it `pip install boto3` then for the following dont forget to replace the necessary informations, we set up our credentials

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_SECRET_KEY
```

then for example for those kind columns names `new_columns = ["new_col1", "new_col2", "new_col3", ...]`

we will have our script like this:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import datetime

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
response = s3.get_object(Bucket='mybucket', Key='mykey')
df = pd.read_csv(response['Body'])
df.columns = ["new_col1", "new_col2", "new_col3"]

timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
csv_buffer = StringIO()
df.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False)
s3.put_object(Bucket='mybucket', Key=f'datetime={timestamp}/export_current_{timestamp}.csv', Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```